# Expression evaluates to an empty image collection in MODIS

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am doing a MODIS analysis as a practice. I am a beginner in this software. When executing the line of code I get the Expression evaluates to an empty image collection:

Here is my code:

```js
//Cargar Poligono
var Peru = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('COUNTRY_NA', 'Perú'))
.geometry();

// Cargar producto NDVI MODIS
var d = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13A2").select('NDVI')
.filterBounds(Peru)
.filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
.map(function(image){return image.clip(Peru);});

//definir parámetro de visulización
var vis = {
  palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'],
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  min: 0.0,
  max: 4000,
  framesPerInterval: 3, // seleccionar escenas por intervalo (más escenas, más rapido)
  dimensions: '600',
};

//generar GIF (ANIMACIÓN)
var gif = d.getVideoThumbURL(vis);
print(gif);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clipped ImageCollection is empty because your clipping geometry is empty.  This is because:

1. The column name for the [USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDOS_LSIB_SIMPLE_2017) FeatureCollection is case-sensitive, use `'country_na'` not `'COUNTRY_NA'`
2. The FeatureCollection uses US-recognized country name, so use the English spelling `'Peru'` instead of `'Perú'`  (or you could also use FIPS code `.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'PE'))`)

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a92d649ebef13f0f3e79590514af25d4

```
var Peru = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Peru'));
// .geometry(); // comment out geometry just for this demo, keep it enabled in your code

print(Peru);

var Peru_not_working1 = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Perú'));
// .geometry();

print(Peru_not_working1);

var Peru_not_working2 = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('COUNTRY_NA', 'Peru'));
// .geometry();

print(Peru_not_working2);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.